# "Controller" to Master Page (C#/MVC 4)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I will have a user's menu that is present in all pages of my application. This menu will contain some logic and data from database. My question is: the navigation menu is on my shared _Layout.cshtml and I need to apply some logic behind this. So, how can I do this? Can I create a "MasterPageController"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Html.RenderAction` or `@Html.Action` from your `_Layout.chsml`, and create a controller/action specifically for your shared component. See [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) for more details.